# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I was trying to create project using spring boot and couchbase(5.1) latest version. When i ran the application using spring boot app. It gives up the following error. All my configuration is proper.

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'couchbaseServerDataAccessImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseServerDataAccessImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'couchbaseServerBucket'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getBucket' defined in class path resource [com/example/persistence/provider/couchbase/server/CouchbaseServerPersistenceProvider.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket]: Factory method 'getBucket' threw exception; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "beer-sample" do not match.

my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>couchdbproj</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>couchdbproj</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Swagger v2.2.2 is conflicting with spring cloud feign. To resolve this, update Swagger to v2.7.0.